# Alamofire header with double quote

Tags: swift, string, xcode

I need to call API with double quote header like this

"Authorization": Token token="xxcxxxxxa"

```
 let favToken = "Token token=/"xxxxxxxxx/""
 let headers = ["Authorization" : favToken]
```

But as I debug, there is always / before double quote so it failed every time.

[image]

Comment: Maybe use the raw string equivalent? `let favToken = #"Token token="xxxxxxxxx""#`

Comment: You are not posting your original code. You are saying it is including a slash but the screen shot shows a backslash. Your code wouldn't even compile as it is. What you probably have in your original code is `"Token token=\"xxxxxxxxx\""` which is correct. The backslash shown is just a representation. it is not actually there in your string

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 5 you can use enhanced delimiters:

```
let favToken = #"Token token="xxxxxxxxx""#
```

if you want variable

```
let favToken = #"Token token="\#(myToken)""#
```

*Demonstrated on Xcode 12.0*
[image: Demonstration]

Comment: Yes, it is right but backslash (\) keeps adding when it is Alamorequest header.

Comment: @KpStar There is nothing being added to your string. Just print it.