# Swift Alamofire Header with Double Quotes(")

Tags: swift, string, xcode

```
  let headers = ["Authorization" : "Token token=\"12312341234\""]
```

Need to add header with double quote but backslash() always keeps adding.

How to remove backslash when it comes to Alamofire header.

[image]

Comment: There is no backslash in your string. Just print the value and you will realize the are not there.

Answer (score -1):

In this case form your token using this format

```
// here second line will be considered as it is 
let token = """
"your token"
"""
```

then use the token like this

```
let headers = ["Authorization" : token]
```

Comment: OP is already using Extended String Delimiters https://stackoverflow.com/a/64589660/2303865

Comment: btw `"Token token=\"12312341234\""` is correct as well